# Magento checkout cart success page on customer suggestion form

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9.1

1. On Checkout cart success page on message after i want display
   suggestion or feedback form with multiple option.
2. After fill information send mail.
3. Comment and feedback option validation without page refresh.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to develop your own module with ajax capabilities, sending information to the controller of your module.

The module should also include a block which should be added in the `checkout_onepage_success` layout.

More on module creation here : [Magento wiki custom module with database](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)

To create the form and have the mail notifications you can check it out at inchoo here:  [Custom email contact form with notification system](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks this was working but i want to send mail using local/email template.